# Server running at 30% CPU after sudden client disconnect with Java NIO, will my fix work?

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

I have an non-blocking NIO server I wrote, for the most part it functions as expected with normal use; however I noticed that on occasion it sticks at 30% CPU usage for some reason. After a lot of time trying to force the bug I eventually triggered it when I disconnected the client right after the `SocketChannel` was accepted but before any bytes were read. This was purely by chance I caught it. I'd spent a good portion of the day trying to catch it and not managing.

It seems to happen once every few days or so. 
I've added the following code:

```
 SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();             
                    if(!channel.isConnected()){
                        key.cancel();
                        break;
                    }
```

And my current server loop now looks like this:

```
    try {

        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        ServerSocket serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort));

        log.info("Selector Thread: Server "
                + Server.SERVER_VERSION
                + " Runnable- Listening for connections on port: "
                + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        running = true;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        SelectionKey serverAcceptKey = serverSocketChannel.register(
                selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        while (running) {
                    selector.select();
            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keyIterator.next();
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                if(!channel.isConnected()){
                    key.cancel();
                    break;
                }
                if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) == SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

                    acceptConnection(selector, key);
                    keyIterator.remove();

                } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ) {

                    readFromSocketChannel(key);
                    keyIterator.remove();

                } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) == SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) {

                    writeToSocketChannel(key);
                    keyIterator.remove();
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.fatal(
                "An IOException occurred, Selector or ServerSocket could not open, shutting down...",
                e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Will the addition of the `if` statement on the current key's channel catch sudden disconnects like the one's I'm occasionally getting? 
It's very rare that these occur and are not handled by OP_READ returning -1 on a read attempt, but they do seem to occur occasionally. will my fix work?

Comment: Why are you breaking out of key processing loop on `!channel.isConnected()` condition? At lest remove that key from the selected keys set.

Comment: Oh god your right! my bad! And of course I shouldn't break the loop there. I 'm putting that down to me not getting much sleep last night. So is the modified if OK?  `if(!channel.isConnected()){
      keyIterator.remove();
     }`

Comment: There is no multithreading or `ServerSocket` here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: It's a multi-threaded server, but this question doesn't contain multithreading. Noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've added the following code:

```
SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();             
if(!channel.isConnected()){
    key.cancel();
    break;
}
```

Pointless. `isConnected()` doesn't magically become false when the connection breaks. It only tells you whether you accepted or connected the channel, which you did. And if it did magically give you a connection status instead of just a channel status, you should close the channel. Not just cancel the key.

What you should put in its place is this:

```
keyIterator.remove(); // unconditionally
if (!key.isValid())
    continue;    // key has been cancelled
```

and remove `keyIterator.remove()` from all the other locations. Possibly this may solve your problem. Otherwise you would have to post more of your code, specifically the code where you read and write from/to the channel, to show where your loop is. For example, if you catch an `IOException` doing either of these operations, you must close the channel concerned: it is broken.

Comment: OK, thank you, that is indeed a much cleaner way to do things. I do handle `IOException` in my read/write operations and I close the channel when it happens.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit embarrassed by it right now, it desperately needs an overhaul as I wrote it a couple of months ago when I'd only started with NIO. I've since done a much neater one that handles other functionality. Maybe when I've done that I'll share :-D . Your suggestion seems to have worked, but I probably won't know for sure for a few more days.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd like to see it because it should not contain loops.

Comment: Thanks! it doesn't. You've been a great help!